# how come I can't update my endless OS using command line?. It brings this error. Is there something wrong in my sources.list?

Tags: debian-based

```
Err:1 http://obs-master.endlessm-sf.com:82/shared/eos eos3.7 InRelease
  Could not connect to obs-master.endlessm-sf.com:82 (52.25.213.40), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                               
Building dependency tree... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://obs-master.endlessm-sf.com:82/shared/eos/dists/eos3.7/InRelease  Could not connect to obs-master.endlessm-sf.com:82 (52.25.213.40), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

These are the only repositories in my source.list folder and sources.list.d is empty:

```
deb http://obs-master.endlessm-sf.com:82/shared/eos eos3.7 core endless
deb-src http://obs-master.endlessm-sf.com:82/shared/eos eos3.7 core endless
```

Answer (score 1):

Endless use a read-only root file system managed by OSTree with application installed using Flatpak. You can use commands like dpkg -l which do not make changes to the system, but you cannot use commands like apt-get install.
Try this in terminal.

( flatpak update --appstream && flatpak update -y )
[endlessos](/questions/tagged/endlessos) [debian-based](/questions/tagged/debian-based)